# How to add body parameter in Serel gem (stackoverflow api)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stackexchange-api

Actually when i try to access a question using serel gem(which is a ruby wrapper for stackoverflow api), i get an object with no body parameter included in it.

```
questions = Serel::Question.find(id)
```

see http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids. According to this, we need to turn the body parameter true.

How to turn the parameter "body" true.

Answer (score 3):

So I finally figured it out, this should work for you:

```
Serel::Question.filter(:withbody).find(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 questions = Serel::Question.find(id).body.get
```

Comment: This doesnt work as body is nil class. see the error             `1.9.3p194 :003 > ques = Serel::Question.find(14779466).body.get
[INFO][2013-02-10 10:58:30] Making request to /2.0/questions/14779466?site=stackoverflow&key=Sd9owvzqRd%29VnsNfrCAJwA%28%28
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):3
 from /home/papri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3p194 :004 > ques = Serel::Question.find(14779466)`